# Store a client datetime into UTC in php

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

When the client sends a string like:

```
2019-07-20T10:00+02:00
```

I want the API to store the datetime in a UTC `DateTimeImmutable` as:

```
2019-07-20T08:00
```

How can this be easily achieved?

```
new DateTimeImmutable('2019-07-20T10:00+02:00');
```

always stores it as `2019-07-20T10:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the timezone with the [setTimezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) method.

```
$dateTime = new DateTimeImmutable('2019-07-20T10:00+02:00');
echo $dateTime->format(DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED) . PHP_EOL;
// 2019-07-20T10:00:00.000+02:00
$dateTime = $dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $dateTime->format(DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED);
// 2019-07-20T08:00:00.000+00:00
```

Comment: works like a charm. I was hoping that it's possible with fewer lines of code, though. I may need to write a helper class then. Thanks!